# Execution of tests in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I have 2 tests that I need to run one after another for several times.

The desired scenario is: "first test", "second test", "first test", "second test" and so on...

The actual scenario is: "first test", "first test", "second test", "second test".

```
@Test (priority = 1, invocationCount = 3)
public void first() {
    System.out.println("first test");
}

@Test (priority = 2, invocationCount = 3)
public void second() {
    System.out.println("second test");
}
```

How can I achieve my desired scenario?

Another requirement here is that on the first test, an Android phone should be the first device and an iOS phone should be the second one.
On the second test, the iOS phone should be the first device and the Android one should be second. 
So it means that I need to use a different xml file.

```
<test name="TwoDevices - ios first">
    <parameter name="appName" value="App2"/>
    <parameter name ="device" value="IOS/iphone6_plus"/>
    <parameter name ="secondDevice" value="ANDROID/lg4_v5"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.TestFactory"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: UnitTet in general are supposed to be executed in any order. So your requirement is not supported by the framework. But you could have a single (annotated) Test method that calles the other methods either directly one after the other or (id setup/teardown also need to be executed)  it selects the method to call based on a (static) counter variable.

Comment: For your situation, it seems the best course of action would be to combine the two tests into one. However, if it is necessary for the tests to be separated, then you can use a factory as others have mentioned.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i must have 2 separate tests. i tried factory but it doesn't work. i will try to perform it with one single test but i am not sure i am allowed.

Comment: Improve formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue resolved after I changed the xml file:

```
<test name="TwoDevices - ios first">
<parameter name="appName" value="App2"/>
<parameter name ="device" value="IOS/iphone6_plus"/>
<parameter name ="secondDevice" value="ANDROID/lg4_v5"/>
<classes>
    <class name="com.MyDebug">
    <methods>
        <include name="first"></include>
    </methods>
    </class>
</classes>
```

```
<test name="TwoDevices - ANDROID first">
<parameter name="appName" value="App2"/>
<parameter name="device" value="ANDROID/lg4_v5"/>
<parameter name="secondDevice" value="IOS/iphone6_plus"/>
<classes>
<class name="com.MyDebug">
    <methods>
        <include name="second"></include>
    </methods>
</class>
</classes>
```

What happens is that only one method runs in the class. After the first execution, the second method runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `@AfterMethod` annotation

```
    @Test (invocationCount=3)
     public void first() {
     System.out.println("first test");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void second() {
    System.out.println("second test");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's not possible due to my work requirement

Comment: Whats your actual requirement?

Comment: I meant that on the afterMethod I run other code. I take screenshots, sends the report and tears the devices. The requirement is to run the first test (android first device, ios second device), and then run the second test (ios as first device, android as second device). Basically to run the tests non stop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `depends on method` property of TestNG:

```
@Test (priority=1,invocationCount = 3)
public void first() {
  System.out.println("first test");
}

@Test (priority=2,invocationCount = 3, dependsOnMethods = { "first" })
public void second() {
  System.out.println("second test");
}
```

Comment: How do you run your tests? if you run from testng xml then you need to compile your project before running, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) and run it (instead of the test class):

```
public class TestFactory {
  @Factory
  public static Object[] createInstances() {
    int number = 3;
    Object[] result = new Object[number]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      result[i] = new Test();
    }
    return result;
  }
}

public class Test {
  @Test
  public void first() {
    System.out.println("first test");
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods="first")
  public void second() {
    System.out.println("second test");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried this solution but the result is the same. the first test runs 3 times and then the second test runs 3 times. anything i missed here?

Comment: Try to add `group-by-instances`: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations Let me know if it is working and I will update my answer.